# Activate face recognition in the new Google Photos

Tags: google-photos

I'm living in Europe and the new Google Photos app does not group the people in my photos in the search menu. I did some research and found out that this function is only available in USA.

Any idea how to activate it in other countries?

As mentioned in the comments, the reason for the absence of this feature is legal issues, so you are responsible for using this work around ;-)

Comment: Some background: there are legal issues for that feature not being (officially) available in Europe ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just found the solution to this. All you need to do is:

1. Connect to a USA server via a VPN
2. Clear the data and cache of the Google Photos app.
3. Open the app again and activate the "Group similar faces" in the settings
4. Check back the search menu after a couple of minutes and the faces would be there. Google already did the recognition for you, but kept it for itself.
5. Disconnect from the VPN.

Comment: "Connect to a USA server..." - hmm, which server do you mean?

Comment: Just a vpn server which is located in united states!  There are many free Vpn service providers with servers in usa,  like cyberghost for example

Comment: thanks for the info it works like charm ,, and just for someone else there is another great free VPN provider for your android or IOS phone,, just search for TUNNELBEAR :)